# why isn't GR showing axis-labels in Julia

Tags: plot, julia, bar-chart

So, I have an array that looks like this:

```
7-element Vector{Pair{Any, Any}}:
 "Python hand-written" => 3104.096806
    "Python- Built-in" => 2488.479628
  "Julia hand-written" => 14.478426
                   "C" => 13.675734
        "C ffast-math" => 7.390966
      "Julia built-in" => 5.510281
        "Python numpy" => 4.949694
```

I'm trying to plot this data in a horizontal bar plot, but for some reason I receive the error:

```
GKS: Rectangle definition is invalid routine SET_VIEWPORT
```

this is my piece of code:

```
x = map(x->x[1], l_vec)
y = map(x->x[2], l_vec)

x_ticks = [0, 1, 2, 3,4, 5,  1000, 1500, 2000, 2500]

bar(x ,y , color="dark blue",
    xaxis = ("time (ms)",:log10, 45),
    yaxis = ("Languages"),
    orientation= :horizontal,label = "" ,fillrange=1e-2, xticks =(x_ticks, x_ticks))
```

I'm not sure I understand this error...[image: Plot without the axis]

Comment: I'm also interested in what is `Julia hand-written`, can you post on discourse of your benchmark?

Comment: by discourse you mean https://discourse.julialang.org/? sure, I can. You can also find it in my github page: https://github.com/hdcpereira/aprendendo-julia/blob/main/how_fast_is_julia_sum.ipynb

Comment: you want to allow Julia to use simd, `@simd for a in A`, numpy certainly uses

Comment: care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are asking to place a label at `x=0` on a logscale.

BTW, I'd recommend [against plotting bars on a logscale](https://www.graphpad.com/support/faq/graph-tip-dont-use-a-log-scale-on-a-bar-graph/).

If you really want the logscaled bars, remove the zero in `x_ticks` and you'll get

[image]

Comment: Ok, that was the silliest thing i have ever asked here. Thank you though